# MySQL group_concat problems

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, group-concat

I have multiple tables that I need to concatenate a group of results from.  There is 6 tables overall with a index in each matching the primary_key in the initial table.

However, when I execute my query it results in multiple instances of each result being returned for each table.  If i select just one record the output is fine.  It seems that the query is being ran multiple times per table and all the results are being concatenated together.

```
    SELECT id, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb1.table1) AS tbl1,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb2.table2) AS tbl2,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb3.table3) AS tbl3,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb4.table4) AS tbl4,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tb5.table5 )AS tbl5
    FROM table t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, field2
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY id
    ) tb1
    ON tb1.id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, field2
        FROM table2
        GROUP BY id
    ) tb2
    ON tb2.id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, field2
        FROM table3
        GROUP BY id
    ) tb3
    ON tb3.id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, field2
        FROM table4
        GROUP BY id
    ) tb4
    ON tb4.id = t.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT id, field2
        FROM table5
        GROUP BY id
   ) tb5
   ON tb5.id = t.id
   GROUP BY t.id
```

I expected/want the results to be.

```
Primary Key | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5
1           |  1, 2   |  2, 3   |  2, 4   |  1, 5   |  NUll
```

But the returned results are, this is only an example of 1 row when not specifying a record id, however all rows appear like this.

```
Primary Key | Field 1 | Field 2 | Field 3 | Field 4 | Field 5
1           | 1,2     | 2,3,    | 2,4     | 1,5,    |  NUll
2           | 1,2,1,  | 2,3,2,  | 2,4,2,  | 1,5,1,  |  1
2           | 1,2,1,2 | 2,3,2,3 | 2,4,2,4 | 1,5,1,5 |  1, 2
```

I am at a loss where or why the query is iterating over itself multiple times and then iterating over each table.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Edit:  I have updated my initial desired results and added more rows to how the table is being brought back.

Also included a 4 table schema:
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    );

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table1id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX (`table1id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table3` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table1id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX (`table1id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table4` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `table1id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX (`table1id`)
);

INSERT INTO `table`(`id`, `Name`) VALUES (1, 'Test'),(2, 'Second Test'),(3,'Third Test'),(4, 'Test Four'),(5,'Test Five');
INSERT INTO `table2` (`id`,`table1id`, `Name`) VALUES (1,1,'Test Value'), (2,2, 'Test Value 2'), (3,3, 'Test Value 3');
INSERT INTO `table3` (`id`,`table1id`, `Name`) VALUES (1,2,'Value'), (2,3, 'Value 2'), (3,4, 'Value 3');
INSERT INTO `table4` (`id`,`table1id`, `Name`) VALUES (1,1,'Test'), (2,2, 'Test 2'), (3,5, 'Test 3');
```

Comment: Let's pretend that there are only 3 tables, each with 2 columns. Consider providing proper DDLs for that (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT` for all columns in `GROUP_CONCAT()`

Try this:

```
SELECT t.id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb1.field2) AS tbl1,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb2.field2) AS tbl2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb3.field2) AS tbl3,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb4.field2) AS tbl4,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tb5.field2) AS tbl5
FROM TABLE t
LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 tb1 ON tb1.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 tb2 ON tb2.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 tb3 ON tb3.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 tb4 ON tb4.id = t.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN table5 tb5 ON tb5.id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: You can also, if need be, put an ORDER BY clause in group_concat like so   `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT thing ORDER BY thing)` to ensure your comma separated lists are in order.

Comment: Tried this but it only returns 1 row not all of the rows in the database.  Removing the group by t.id results in the same problem as before.  I will try and sort out an SqlFiddle of my table to try and give example.